# Ancient IE browser on dinosaur running xp 2003 can't connect to the internet

Tags: networking, windows-xp, internet-explorer

So I'm playing around with a fossil that I made the mistake of purchasing at a local thrift store; one which can't even run a browser in lubuntu (not enough processing power, I think). Lubuntu is installed on an external drive via usb, so the original xp sp-1 is still installed on the original hard drive (a system restore to manufacturer defaults somehow recovered the crashing ide hard drive).

Just as an experiment, I'd like to update xp and see if this piece of hardware can even run it once updated. But this thing updates via internet explorer, and the explorer won't connect to the internet. The system dns settings are correct, and the browser can access the modem settings page, but not the internet. help?

update: internet explorer version is 6, explorer has connection options for setting up a dialup or vpn connection, and separate options for a lan connection. internet is connected, pings to 8.8.8.8 and www.google.com are successful.

I'm not sure IE6 can work through a modem. If it can, I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52976/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-hahn-ancient-ie-browser-on-dinosuar-running).

Answer (score 0):

The pc was able to connect to the internet, but internet explorer wasn't, and this version of windows was set up to update through IE, via a website which doesn't exist anymore. I had to find sp-2 and sp-3, which aren't hosted by microsoft anymore, so that I could install programs which would accomplish my ends (update windows and browse the web). I also installed windows installer 3.1, net framework 2, and windows update downloader (WUD). I have installed dillo and qupzilla light browsers, which work well enough, and I'll be installing a driver update utility when WUD finishes installing updates (more framework stuff, security stuff, and IE8).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer or the version therein has nothing to do with a computer being able to connect to a network via a dial-up modem.
The Intel 4, 2.8 GHz (assuming this is the same pc you referenced in a previous question pointing to this question) has plenty of processing power and more than enough for running a browser as browsing software does not require much cpu power in itself. You may be trying to open something that utilizes flashplayer, for example or something similar, and don't have the latest updates on that add-in or module.

Windows XP in terms of SP1 and 2 is a lost cause unless you update the RAM even though I have gotten XP with service pack 1 and (I think even SP2) to run on 256MB of RAM but it takes an awefull lot of back-end tweaking and is not for the average person unless you want to go after the fulfilling accomplishment of solving huge pc puzzles. Could be fun, educating and interesting in an aggravating sort of way if your into that kind of thing.

If you don't upgrade RAM, 256Mb of RAM may run Puppy Linux just fine but you need an OS with a small footprint specifically designed to run on older hardware Like Puppy is designed to do. I would check into Puppy as this distro is amazing in terms of what they have done with it. At last check it was between 400-500MB and is fully functioning for a desktop Linux distro.

IE v6.0 is not only unstable and non-secure but is so deprecated and will not adequately display most websites written in just the basics of modern HTML5. You will get constant error messages on most websites telling you to upgrade your browser such as:

[image]

Although I am pretty sure that any Microsoft website is just going to refuse your IE6 browser at this point. IE 8 was the last version available for XP and is also deprecated and unsecure and it will also happily provide the constant 'You need to upgrade' messages.
Windows XP may have initially updated through the browser by going to Microsoft's default webpage www.windowsupdate.com which is where you can go if the WinUpdate (WU) tool is not functioning on a pc. The initial Windows update tool that was used through XP SP1 will at some point stop functioning (after a certain update point as there is an update disabling it) as it has been deprecated for a new updated tool release. This new update tool will not download from MS (since after April 2014) and would have to be installed manually.

XP SP1 and 2 can still be found on the web even though not hosted my MS but I have updated XP on a machine some 6-8 months after April 2014 as you could still get all update up till and 6-8 months after the date they dropped mainstream support even though at the time, I could see the possibility at some point they may no longer host them.

Comment: You are commenting in the Answer section. This is not what the answer section is for. Please take the time to review the [TOUR](http://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: dsl modem, not dial up. websites actually worked with ie6 after service pack updates. I got ie8 and some other stuff installed with WUD, and the windows updater worked with ie8. I got everything updated and it ran well enough for a while, but the hard drive is still bad and I'm already getting bad sectors. (I can't download anything now. it downloads completely but then I get a cycle something or other error. I looked it up and it points back to the hard disk, which if you've seen my other question, was crashed when I got this thing). So I'm not going to get around buying a hard drive adapter.

Comment: Last HDD molex to sata power adapter I purchased cost me $2.50. I was in a hurry since the one previous only cost me $1.67. So, its not really a huge investment. And I forgot you also need the controller card which is only about $5-$6

Comment: according to about 2 hours of scouring reviews, about $15 for an adapter that won't arrive dead, burn out after a month, be slow and unreliable, or damage other components. the adapter in question does convert both power and the rest via one device, and is bidirectional.